# Need help for overflow-y:auto/ scrolling

Tags: html, css

I just create this div function:

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-12">
    <!--<img src="images/article_image.png" class="img-responsive" />-->
    <?php //echo $wordRow['article_image']; ?>
    <h2 class="black_color" style="font-size: 25px; font-style:italic ;margin-left:15px">
      <?php echo $wordRow['article_name']; ?>
    </h2>
    <div class="black_color" style="margin-left:20px; margin-right:20px; overflow-y:auto;">
      <?php echo $wordRow['article_description']; ?>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

which gives me this [white form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hsoqe.jpg) , which is part of [this editor.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BUT9O.jpg) By that I'm able to create articles on my site. Unfortunalety I get the scrolling on the side if the text is longer. I try do add

```html
overflow-y:auto;
```

but that doesn't work. Putting a max length for the text doesn't work either. Basicly what I'm trying to do is to put a scrolling inside the white article form and not on the left of the page. Any ideas?

Comment: what is the problem? the scrolling? put a max-height on the div and overflow:scroll;

Comment: See answer below.

Comment: see my answer, you use a lot of inline style, which can be a pain if you make later changes. By using css stylesheets, when you link in a stylesheet, once you make a change to the css to an id/class in the stylesheet, the change is applied across the site. Look into it. I have provided the css for your current page. You could put it into the style section in the head of your page but it's not recommended practice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set two overflow properties, overflow-x and overflow y

Set the overflow-y to scroll and overflow-x to hidden on the same div and then it'll work just as well

If you give your divs ids and classes you can avoid inline-style and use css stylesheets (a lot easier!)

for example on the outer div you could give id of outer, and the inner div, inner. Your css/style section would look like this (example). Externally linked in stylesheets are preferred/recommended

```
#outer{height:100%}


#inner{width: 98%;
       color:#000000;
        overflow-y:scroll;
        overflow-x:hidden;
        margin-left: 20px; 
        margin-right:20px;
  }

h2{color:#000000;
   font-size: 25px; 
   font-style:italic ;
    margin-left:15px}
```

Comment: I did it earlier like that, but it is not working. I think it's because of the ckeditor. If i add the styles in the css nothing changes. Even mine code.

Comment: I get this using your [way](http://imgur.com/a/AGRNX), the text goes beneath the white form. But when I'm using my code I'm getting [this](http://imgur.com/a/uBNJF). You also put h2, but that needs to be specifide trough the ckeditor.

Comment: there seems to be very little difference. You had width specified at 98.5, i put 98%, if you widen it a bit it would probably be the same?

Comment: i appreciate it. And you earned badges and rep for doing so! :)  I noticed what the difference was actually , apart from the width. Yours was scrolling on the outer div, my code scrolled on the inner div. Eureka! :)

Answer (score 0):

This helped me pretty much.

```html
<div style="height:100%; overflow:hidden">
    <div style="width:98.5%; position: fixed; bottom:23px; top: 137.5px; overflow:auto">
       <h2 class="black_color" style="font-size: 25px; font-style:italic ;margin-left:15px"><?php echo $wordRow['article_name']; ?>
      </h2>
      <div class="black_color" style="margin-left:20px; margin-right:20px;">
        <?php echo $wordRow['article_description']; ?>
     </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

I now get the scrolling inside the form, like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/go6lv.png) and the whole page stays in place. So will the text stay inside the the white form.

Answer (score 0):

This helps too:

```css
#outer {
    height: 100%
    overflow: hidden;
}
#inner {
    width: 98.5%;
    position: fixed;
    overflow:auto;
    bottom:23px; 
    top: 137.5px;
}
```

```html
<div id="outer">
  <div id="inner">
    <h2 class="black_color" style="font-size: 25px; font-style:italic ;margin-left:15px"><?php echo $wordRow['article_name']; ?></h2>
    <div class="black_color" style="margin-left:20px; margin-right:20px;"><?php echo $wordRow['article_description']; ?></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Either way is good.